# In the equation: $ab - cd = f $, how do I get $a$, $c,$ and $f$, all on the same side?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 
$$ab - cd = f$$

My goal is to isolate the variables $a$, $c$, and $f$  on one side, and the variables $b$ and $d$ on the other. That is all.

Comment: No way,  cannot be done.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?